# Trouble with ImageList component in Material-UI - Need Guidance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, imagelist

I'm currently working with the ImageList component in Material-UI, and I've encountered some difficulties achieving a specific behavior. I've gone through the documentation, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Here is what I am trying to achieve]

I've already checked the official docs about the Image List in MUI but didn't find any solution.

It would be great if someone could provide me with some guidance.